# Syntax error db

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, delphi-xe2

This code:

```
Adoquery1.close;
Adoquery1.SQL.Clear;
sql := 'INSERT INTO Keywords (Keyword_Text) VALUE ( :keys )';
Adoquery1.SQL.Add(sql);
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('keys').Value:= Lowercasek;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Keeps giving me

> syntax error INSERT INTO

Debugging shows me that the value of `keys` is correct ("best"), the db name is correct ("Keywords") and the field is correct ("Keyword_Text").

```
Sql reads = 'INSERT INTO Keywords (Keyword_Text) VALUE ( :keys )'
```

See any reason why I get this error?

Comment: Can this help you: `sql := 'INSERT INTO Keywords (Keyword_Text) VALUE ( ":keys" )'`;

Comment: `VALUES` instead of `VALUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is `VALUES` (not `VALUE`). Try this:

```
sql := 'INSERT INTO Keywords (Keyword_Text) VALUES ( :keys )';
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess having just one value threw me off to use values instead of value